# Can i broadcast a transaction by my other geth-core?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have serveral geth-core running on different regions cloud-server, one running on my local computer.

I don't know why my geth-core(local computer) can't keep up the newest block , it always delay about 10w block. but my geth-core on cloud-server is sync the newest block.

Sometime i want to send a transaction from my local computer , it will return the tips about balance not enought (the balance had not sync to the newest block ).

So, how can i broadcast the transaction by my other cloud-server using json-rpc ? i don't want to send my keystore to my cloud-server .

Thx.

Comment: never heard of `geth-core` , what is it?

Comment: i mean running the go-ethereum ...

Answer (score 0):

You can sign the transaction on your local computer and then send the raw signed transaction to the cloud computer.
You are correct that you should never send your keys to a cloud-computer!

Comment: Thanks Ligi . I found the api like that eth_sign  eth_sendRawTransaction ~ i don't know how to get the eth_sign param data .  Is there any example about sign a trasaction data can show me ?